# Inconsistent busy waiting time in c

Tags: c, time, printf, busy-waiting, gettimeofday

I have a character that should "eat" for 200 microseconds, "sleep" for 200 microseconds, and repeat, until they die, which happens if they haven't eaten for `time_to_die` microseconds.

In the code snippet in function `main` indicated below, the struct `time_to_die` has a member `tv_usec` configured for 1000 microseconds and I expect it to loop forever.

After some time, one execution of the function `busy_wait` takes around 5 times more than it is supposed to (enough to kill the character), and the character dies. I want to know why and how to fix it.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct timeval  time_add_microseconds(struct timeval time, long long microseconds)
{
    
    time.tv_usec += microseconds;
    while (time.tv_usec >= 1000000)
    {
        time.tv_sec += 1;
        time.tv_usec -= 1000000;
    }
    return (time);
}


short   time_compare(struct timeval time_one, struct timeval time_two)
{
    if (time_one.tv_sec != time_two.tv_sec)
    {
        if (time_one.tv_sec > time_two.tv_sec)
            return (1);
        else
            return (-1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (time_one.tv_usec > time_two.tv_usec)
            return (1);
        else if (time_one.tv_usec == time_two.tv_usec)
            return (0);
        else 
         return (-1);
    }
}

// Wait until interval in microseconds has passed or until death_time is reached.
void    busy_wait(int interval, struct timeval last_eaten_time, struct timeval time_to_die)
{
    struct timeval      time;
    struct timeval      end_time;
    struct timeval      death_time;

    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    end_time = time_add_microseconds(time, interval);
    death_time = time_add_microseconds(last_eaten_time, time_to_die.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time_to_die.tv_usec);
    while (time_compare(time, end_time) == -1)
    {
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        if (time_compare(time, death_time) >= 0)
        {
            printf("%llu died\n", time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval time;
    struct timeval time_to_die = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 1000};
    struct timeval last_eaten_time = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 0 };

    while (true)
    {
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        printf("%llu eating\n", time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec);
        last_eaten_time = time;
        busy_wait(200, last_eaten_time, time_to_die);

        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        printf("%llu sleeping\n", time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec);
        busy_wait(200, last_eaten_time, time_to_die);
    }
}
```

Note: Other than the system functions I already used in my code, I'm only allowed to use usleep, write, and malloc and free.

Thank you for your time.

Note: I had mistaken confused milliseconds with microseconds, and that was the problem all along...

Comment: How longer is "significantly more than it's supposed to"?

Comment: If you can't use any system function other than `usleep`, `write`, `malloc` and `free`, then why is `gettimeofday()` all over your program?  I'm not being facetious: if that's really not on the list of functions you may use, then you are probably running down a rabbit hole.  It may be that you're not meant to be measuring wall time at all.

Comment: Works as (if I understood correctly) expected on my computer. But have you tried with significantly higher timings. Just to check the logic? And then try to reduce timings.

Comment: Plus, you are using printf in the middle of your loop. Depending on your terminal, that may be very slow (I mean, not from a human-machine interaction time point of view. But from a "measuring time in microsecond" point of view)

Comment: @chrslg, the `printf` in the busy wait loop is executed only in the event that the death time has already been reached.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, but it is between the measurement of time, and the start of the active loop that must end before eating time. So, if that printf takes 1 ms (which is very long, I know), then the next waiting loop will end up with a starving. Because of the printf.

Comment: I don't put my money on this hypothesis. But I wouldn't discard it without checking. Because I have seen some very fancy but very slow terminals for which a single 25 lines long page takes a good part of a second to scroll. So, way more than 1 ms for a line. Even linux text console (I mean no X. Ctrl+Alt+F1) is that slow with some framebuffer settings. Not to mention running over ssh, but I supposed this would have been specified.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're talking about the `while` loop in `main`, and the `printf` there that announces that the character is sleeping.  Yeah, I guess it's plausible that that sometimes takes a long time.

Comment: But, well, on my slow computer, it runs as expected. (With some 210 µs between each lines, so only 10µs of overhead in addition to the 200 µs expected). So, there must be a reason for that. And that reason has to lie on some "environmental" differences between the OP's computer and mine, since it is not in the code.

Comment: @chrslg thanks for the ideas. I tried commenting out all the printfs, but the problem persists. I tried testing my code on replit, it fails there also (the character dies).

Comment: For example, just tried on my text console (which I thought was fast. I mean, that is my fast settings of text mode. It is supposed to be a really text console — my graphics card is supposed to be in a mode where it receives ascii code, not pixels (tho I never was sure of it. It was simpler back in the days; and faster for this usage). And the code dies. Either after 1 iteration, or 2. When it doesn't die at first, 900 μs are spent. When it dies, 1100 μs are.

Comment: Maybe also your computer is just slow. Or is busy. Depending on the scheduling policy (for example for servers), maybe your process is deprived of cpu times for a whole 1ms once in a while, and that makes your character die.

Comment: You could try to create just an empty loop to measure the execution time of those gettimeofday (with or without the printf, depending on whether you want to measure those as well. If without, just store the times got from gettimeofday in an array long enough. And then print time delay at the end, after a few seconds of measurement.

Answer (score 1):

> after some time, one execution of the function busy_wait takes around 5 times more than it is supposed to (enough to kill the character), and the character dies. I want to know why and how to fix it.

There are multiple possibilities.  Many of them revolve around the fact that there is more going on in your computer while the program runs than just the program running. Unless you're running on a realtime operating system, the bottom line is that you *can't* fix some of the things that could cause such behavior.

For example, your program shares the CPU with the system itself and with all the other processes running on it.  That may be more processes than you think: right now, there are over 400 live processes on my 6-core workstation. When there are more processes demanding CPU time than there are CPUs to run them on, the system will split the available time among the contending processes, preemptively suspending processes when their turns expire.

If your program happens to be preempted during a busy wait, then chances are good that substantially more than 200 μs of wall time will elapse before it is next scheduled any time on a CPU.  Time slice size is usually measured in milliseconds, and on a general-purpose OS, there is no upper (or lower) bound on the time between the elapse of one and the commencement of the same program's next one.

---

As I did in comments, I observe that you are using `gettimeofday` to measure elapsed time, yet that is not on your list of allowed system functions.  One possible resolution of that inconsistency is that you're not meant to perform *measurements* of elapsed time, but rather to assume / simulate.  For example, `usleep()` *is* on the list, so perhaps you're meant to `usleep()` instead of busy wait, and assume that the sleep time is exactly what was requested.  Or perhaps you're meant to just adjust an internal time counter instead of actually pausing execution at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my allowed functions list was ambiguous, I edited my post to clarify it. I'm, in fact, allowed to use `gettimeofday`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why

Ultimately: because an interrupt or trap is delivered to the CPU core executing your program, which transfers control to the operating system.

Some common causes:

1. The operating system is running its process scheduling using a hardware timer which fires a regular intervals. I.e. the OS is running some kind of fair scheduler and it has to check if your process' time is up for now.
2. Some device in your system needs to be serviced. E.g. a packet arrived over the network, your sound card's output buffer is running low and must be refilled, etc.
3. Your program voluntarily makes a request to the operating system that transfers control to it. Basically: anytime you make a syscall, the kernel may have to wait for I/O, or it may decide that it's time to schedule a different process, or both. In your case, the calls to `printf` will at some point result in a write(2) syscall that will end up performing some I/O.

#### What to do

Cause 3 can be avoided by ensuring that no syscalls are made, i.e. never trapping in to the OS.

Causes 1 and 2 are *very* difficult to completely get rid of. You're essentially looking for a real-time operating system (RTOS). An OS like Linux can approximate that by placing processes in different scheduling domains (`SCHED_FIFO`/`SCHED_RR`). If you're willing to switch to a kernel that is tailored towards real-time applications, you can get even further. You can also look in to topics like "CPU isolation".

Comment: Linux also has "full tickless mode" which disables timer interrupts on some cores

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate the printf, but also gettimeofday timings I was mentionned in comments, I tried 2 things

```c
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval time;

    long long histo[5000];

    for(int i=0; i<5000; i++){
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        histo[i]=time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec;
    }

    long long min=1000000000;
    long long max=0;
    for(int i=1; i<5000; i++){
        long long dt=histo[i]-histo[i-1];
        if(dt<min) min=dt;
        if(dt>max) max=dt;
        if(dt>800) printf("%d %lld\n", i, dt);
    }
    printf("avg: %f min=%lld max=%lld\n", (histo[4999]-histo[0])/5000.0, min, max);
}
```

So all it does here, is just looping in 5000 printf/gettimeofday iterations. And then measuring (after the loop) the mean, min and max.

On my X11 terminal (Sakura), average is 8 μs per loop, with min 1 μs, and max 3790 μs! (other measurement I made show that this 3000 or so μs is also the only one over 200 μs. In other words, it never goes over 200 μs. Except when it does "bigly").
So, on average, everything goes well. But once in a while, a printf takes almost 4ms (which is not enough, it that doesn't happen several times in a row for a human user to even notice it. But is way more than needed to make your code fail).

On my console (no X11) terminal (a 80x25 terminal, that may, or may not use text mode of my graphics card, I never was sure), mean is 272 μs, min 193 μs, and max is 1100 μs. Which (retroactively) is not surprising. This terminal is slow, but simpler, so less prone to "surprises".
But, well, it fails faster, because probability of going over 200 μs is very high, even if it is not a lot over, more than half of the loops take more than 200 μs.

I also tried measurements on a loop without printf.

```c
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval time;
    long long old=0;

    long long ntot=0;
    long long nov10=0;
    long long nov100=0;
    long long nov1000=0;

    for(int i=0;;i++){
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        long long t=time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec;
        if(old){
            long long dt=t-old;
            ntot++;
            if(dt>10){
                nov10++;
                if(dt>100){
                    nov100++;
                    if(dt>1000) nov1000++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(i%10000==0){
            printf("tot=%lld >10=%lld >100=%lld >1000=%lld\n", ntot, nov10, nov100, nov1000);
            old=0;
        }else{
            old=t;
        }
    }

}
```

So, it measures something that I could pompously call a "logarithmic histogram" of timings.
This times, independent from the terminal (I put back old to 0 each times I print something so that those times doesn't count)

Result

```
tot=650054988 >10=130125 >100=2109 >1000=2
```

So, sure, 99.98% of the times, gettimeofday takes less than 10μs.
But, 3 times each millions call (and that means, in your code, only a few seconds), it takes more than 100μs. And twice in my experiment, it took more than 1000 μs. Just gettimeofday, not the printf.

Obviously, it's not gettimeofday that took 1ms. But simply, something more important occurred on my system, and that process had to wait 1ms to get some cpu time from the scheduler.

And bear in mind that this is on my computer. And on my computer, your code runs fine (well, those measurement shows that it would have failed eventually if I let it run as long as I let those measurements run).

On your computer, those numbers (the 2 >1000) are certainly way more, so it fails very quickly.

preemptive multitasks OS are simply not made to guarantee executions times in micro-seconds. You have to use a Real Time OS for that (RT-linux for example. It it sills exist, anyway — I haven't used it since 2002).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answers, there is no way to make this code work as I expected without a major change in its design, within my constraints. So I changed my code to not depend on `gettimeofday` for determining whether a philosopher died, or determining the time value to print. Instead, I just add 200 μs to `time` every time my character eats/sleeps.  This does feel like a cheap trick. Because while at the start I display the correct system wall time, my time variable will differentiate from the system time more and more as the program runs, but I guess this is what was wanted from me.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct timeval  time_add_microseconds(struct timeval time, long long microseconds)
{
    
    time.tv_usec += microseconds;
    while (time.tv_usec >= 1000000)
    {
        time.tv_sec += 1;
        time.tv_usec -= 1000000;
    }
    return (time);
}


short   time_compare(struct timeval time_one, struct timeval time_two)
{
    if (time_one.tv_sec != time_two.tv_sec)
    {
        if (time_one.tv_sec > time_two.tv_sec)
            return (1);
        else
            return (-1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (time_one.tv_usec > time_two.tv_usec)
            return (1);
        else if (time_one.tv_usec == time_two.tv_usec)
            return (0);
        else 
         return (-1);
    }
}

bool    is_destined_to_die(int interval, struct timeval current_time, struct timeval last_eaten_time, struct timeval time_to_die)
{
    current_time = time_add_microseconds(current_time, interval);
    if ((current_time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + current_time.tv_usec) - (last_eaten_time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + last_eaten_time.tv_usec) >= time_to_die.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time_to_die.tv_usec)
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}

// Wait until interval in microseconds has passed or until death_time is reached.
void    busy_wait(int interval, struct timeval current_time, struct timeval last_eaten_time, struct timeval time_to_die)
{
    struct timeval      time;
    struct timeval      end_time;
    struct timeval      death_time;

    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    if (is_destined_to_die(interval, current_time, last_eaten_time, time_to_die))
    {   
        death_time = time_add_microseconds(last_eaten_time, time_to_die.tv_sec * 1000000 + time_to_die.tv_usec);
        while (time_compare(time, death_time) == -1)
            gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        printf("%llu died\n", time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec);
        exit(1);
    }
    end_time = time_add_microseconds(time, interval);
    while (time_compare(time, end_time) == -1)
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);

}

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval time;
    struct timeval time_to_die = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 1000};
    struct timeval last_eaten_time = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 0 };

    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    while (true)
    {
        printf("%llu eating\n", time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec);
        last_eaten_time = time;
        busy_wait(200, time, last_eaten_time, time_to_die);
        time = time_add_microseconds(time, 200);

        printf("%llu sleeping\n", time.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + time.tv_usec);
        busy_wait(200, time, last_eaten_time, time_to_die);
        time = time_add_microseconds(time, 200);
    }
}
```